# C# how to read only selected value in byte array[]?

Tags: c#, .net

I have array byte like this in c# :

```
byte[] reply = new byte[] {0x09, 0x02, 0x08, 0x63, 0x01, 0x01, 0x10, 0x21, 0x03, 0x5D, 0x01, 0x06};
```

How to only read { 0x01, 0x06 } value in byte array?
What must I do? I'm really a newbie in C#. Thanks for attention.

Comment: [C# Array Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: don't you get error while declaring the byte error.?

Comment: yes i forgot commas.

Comment: To use hex values as literals, prefix with `0x`, so `0x21` and `0x5D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I think you're declaring the array in the wrong way, you're missing the commas.

```
byte[] reply = new byte[] {09, 02, 08, 63, 01, 01, 10, 21, 03, 5D, 01, 06};
```

Next, if you know the 2 values you want to read: (add `using System.Linq;` to your namespaces first)

```
byte[] values = reply.Where(val => val == 01 || val == 06).ToArray();
```

Or, if you have the values you need in another array:

```
byte[] need = new byte[] { 01, 06 };
byte[] values = reply.Where(val => need.Contains(val)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your initialization is wrong.

1. The values should be comma separated.
2. Values like '5D' are not of datatype byte.

   ```
   byte[] reply = new byte[] {0x09, 0x02, 0x08, 0x63, 0x01, 0x01, 0x10, 0x21, 0x03, 0x5D, 0x01, 0x06};
   var answer = reply.Where(x => x.Equals(0x01) || x.Equals(0x06));
   ```

Comment: Yes, `5d` is a (also) double literal, but the OP meant a byte value in hex format. The correct way would be `0x5D`.